# drush is not making a sub theme

Tags: drupal, drush

my command vishal@vishal-linux:~/Dropbox/sites/residen$ drush zen "residen theme" --path=sites/all/themes/

the output :

```
Source directory /home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen//STARTERKIT is not readable or does     not exist.    [error]
rename(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/STARTERKIT.info.txt,/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/residen_theme.info):[warning]
No such file or directory drush.inc:798
file_get_contents(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/residen_theme.info): failed to open stream: No such    [warning]
file or directory zen.drush.inc:115
file_put_contents(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/residen_theme.info): failed to open stream: No such    [warning]
file or directory zen.drush.inc:117
file_get_contents(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/theme-settings.php): failed to open stream: No such    [warning]
file or directory zen.drush.inc:115
file_put_contents(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/theme-settings.php): failed to open stream: No such    [warning]
file or directory zen.drush.inc:117
file_get_contents(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/template.php): failed to open stream: No such file or  [warning]
directory zen.drush.inc:115
file_put_contents(/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme/template.php): failed to open stream: No such file or  [warning]
directory zen.drush.inc:117
Starter kit for "residen theme" created in: /home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/residen/sites/all/themes/residen_theme
```

however the theme dir was not created. I am not sure what went wrong. I am new to drush and zen. Please advice.

Thank you,
Vishal

Comment: the solution is 'drupal cc all' this clears the cache and then it works